# Geometry 2019 TST

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Inside a triangle  $\Delta ABC$ We choose a point $P$. Then draw $BP$ and $CP$ to intersect $AC$ and $AB$ at $E$ and $F$ respectively . Then draw $EF$ to intersect the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$ at $X$ and $Y$.

Then call the circumcenter of $\Delta PXY$ , $O'$.

Prove $O'P$ is perpendicular to $BC$ if and only if $\angle  BAP= \angle  CAP$[image]

Made by myself

I guess I have seen $s^{th}$ similar in some European country TST in year $2014-2015$.

But we used it in an exam three day ago and no one solved and we got that our solution had a typo so we now want to find the correct answer.

Comment: "Plz answer soon" That's not how this site works. Well, it's not how we want it to work. Some times an answer does pop up out of nowhere. But we don't really want to solve math problems here, we want to help people. So in order to help us help you, please provide some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). For instance, where is this problem from, and what have you done to try to solve this?

Comment: Please provide the source of this problem. If it's from an on-going contest, then posting (or answering) it violates the Math.SE community guidelines.

Comment: It's not from an ongoing contest . I posted it about two days ago in AOPS

Comment: @Noone Can you provide the link for the AoPS post?